# Check if all values returns true or false

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, contextmenu

I've got a function:

```
var registerEnabledEvents = function ($scope, enabled, item, $ul, $li, nestedMenu, model, text, event, $, level) {
        /// <summary>If item is enabled, register various mouse events.</summary>
        if (enabled) {
            var openNestedMenu = function ($event) {
                removeContextMenus(level + 1);
                var ev = {
                    pageX: event.pageX + $ul[0].offsetWidth - 1,
                    pageY: $ul[0].offsetTop + $li[0].offsetTop - 3
                };
                renderContextMenu($scope, ev, nestedMenu, model, level + 1);
            };

            $li.on('click', function ($event) {
                $event.preventDefault();
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    if (nestedMenu) {
                        openNestedMenu($event);
                    } else {
                        $(event.currentTarget).removeClass('context');
                        removeContextMenus();

                        if (angular.isFunction(item[1])) {
                            item[1].call($scope, $scope, event, model, text)
                        } else {
                            item.click.call($scope, $scope, event, model, text);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

            $li.on('mouseover', function ($event) {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    if (nestedMenu) {
                        openNestedMenu($event);
                    }
                });
            });
        } else {
            $li.on('click', function ($event) {
                $event.preventDefault();
            });
            $li.addClass('display-none');
        }

    };
```

This function is taken from this angular directive https://github.com/Templarian/ui.bootstrap.contextMenu
to have a context menu. Actually there isn't any way to hide a list item of the menu by a parameter or condition so i modified the directive. i changed:

```
$li.addClass('disabled');
```

with

```
$li.addClass('display-none');
```

It works. If an item returns `false` it doesn't display it. What's the problem? Well the "enabled" parameter returns if the items of the context menu are visible or not. If you write down a console.log() and display that value it will get (if you have 2 items for example):

```
2016-07-08 12:54:36.851 contextMenu.js:141 false 
2016-07-08 12:54:36.854 contextMenu.js:141 false
```

or

```
2016-07-08 12:54:36.851 contextMenu.js:141 true 
2016-07-08 12:54:36.854 contextMenu.js:141 false
```

it depends of course from the conditions in the controller. The problem is that if all items returns false, the context menu it shows without items, but it shows with just a "white empty rectangle". What i need it should be that if all items returns false i add the class display-none to the entire ul like this:

```
$ul.addClass('display-none');
```

but if at least one is true i add the css class only to the $li item to hide only the one return false. How can i do it? Thank you

EDIT:

this is what i tried

```
$scope.arrayValue = [];
        $scope.arrayValue.push(enabled);

        if($scope.arrayValue.every(enabled)) {
            console.log("All true");
        } else {
            console.log("Not all true");
        }
```

but i get: false is not a function

Comment: First, that's ten gallons of function parameters in a five gallon bucket, and check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Comment: As i said the function isn't mine :D By the way, how would you solve this?

Comment: Store the call results in an array and use `Array.prototype.every` to make sure they're all true, apply the css class as indicated. Check out the link in my first comment.

Comment: check my edit please

Comment: Array.every takes a predicate function. Use your function instead of the result or supply the identity function `x => x`

Comment: Wait, the real problem is that this function starts when i click with the right button of the mouse. But it gets me a console log for each menu item. So it means that it fires the function for 5 times separately if i have 5 menu items. I can't create an array in this way.. understand what i mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116805/discussion-between-jared-smith-and-end-game).